# Displaying Unescaped in Django Template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form with a title and body but for certain cases the title should be autofilled to a value from the page:

To solve this I used a hidden input type:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>Title: </b>
      </td>
      {% url 'forum:new_topic' forum.pk  as the_url %}
      {% ifequal request.path the_url %}
      <td>
        {{ modelform.title}}
      </td>
      {% else %}
      <td>
        {% autoescape off %}
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ modelform.title}}" >
        {% endautoescape %}
        Re:{{ thread.title }}
      </td>
      {% endifequal %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>Body: </b>
      </td>
      <td>
      {{ modelform.body}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

However the way it displays on the page is "> Re: .... and is for some reason not escaping the ending quote and >. I tried single quotes but that prevents submission.

Not sure what direction I should go in.

Comment: Is the same thing happening, if you use {{ modelform.title|safe }} ?

Comment: And also, to me the problem looks like whatever you populate the hidden value with has an unescaped quote in it, otherwise it should not do that...

Comment: yes @webzy the result is the same; what do you mean it has an unescaped quote?

Comment: Well, if your " > gets displayed, and it shouldn't, then maybe your title has some quote in it that is being read by the browser as the end of value.

Comment: title is a CharField from the model, does that inherently have a quote?

Comment: No, but you said "but for certain cases the title should be autofilled to a value from the page"... Do you mean you use some JS to populate that field?

Comment: I mean that the value is ideally set in the views; the only reason I needed that hidden field is that the form would not properly submit without it.